# PostgreSQL: How to revalidate CHECKs

Tags: postgresql

My database has the following structure:

```
CREATE TYPE instrument_type AS ENUM (
    'Stock',
...
    'Currency',
...
);

CREATE FUNCTION get_instrument_type(instrument_id bigint) RETURNS instrument_type
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT instr_type FROM instruments WHERE id = instrument_id);
    END
$$;

CREATE TABLE instruments (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    instr_type instrument_type NOT NULL,
...
);

CREATE TABLE countries_currencies (
...
    curr bigint NOT NULL
        REFERENCES instruments (id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
        CHECK (get_instrument_type(curr) = 'Currency'),
...
);
```

As you can see, I use one common table for instruments. There are a lot of foreign keys referencing to that table. But some tables like countries_currencies require that referenced item is 'Currency'. Since I can't use subqueries in CHECK constraints, I have to use function.
One day it could happen that one bad man will change instrument_type from 'Currency' to something else. If there is a row in table countries_currencies, referencing to modified instrument, CHECK will become invalid for this row. But CHECK will be applied to new rows, not for already existing.

Is there any standard way to revalidate CHECKs? I want to run such procedure as a part of general data integrity test.

P.S. I know, I could write trigger on table instruments and forbid change if something could become broken. But it requires assurance that I check all referencing tables and their constraints, so it is error prone anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to think if there's an alternative approach to this that binds the constraint into the schema rather than relying on procedural code. It could even be a case for table inheritance, since you want to treat the specific subset of `instruments` that are actually `currencies` as their own entity in the database. Or, in "simpler" relational normalisation terms, maybe an intermediary `currencies` table that references `instruments` is called for.

Comment: @IMSoP, there are some limitations with inheritance in PostgreSQL. The major one is that there is no unique index along all inherited tables.

Comment: @IMSoP, I try other approaches, but each has its own limitations. Itermediary table approach requires that each row with instr_type = 'currency' must have similar row in intermediary table. So, it requires trigger to copy each currency into intermediary. Another approach is to have instr_type in countries_currencies table and use it in foreign key. But this isn't normalized too. Thank you for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply update all rows in place to trigger the CHECK:

```
UPDATE countries_currencies SET curr = curr;
```

Comment: I was curious whether that would actually work, so I built a quick test case, and it does indeed run the check function: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d2bc5/5

Comment: @PinnyM, thank you. This turns out to be surprisingly simple!